# How to get drawable resources on FAB in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, bottomnavigationview, xml-drawable

I am trying to use a FAB with Bottom NavigationView in my app. I have designed drawable xml resources for that FAB to give the FAB gradient color and an icon along with a drop shadow of custom color. But the problem is when I try to get the drawable xml resource on FAB background attribute it doesn't work and the app crash. I am using **Android Studio version 4.2.2** with **Android Gradle plugin version 4.1.3** and **Gradle Version 6.7.1**.

**Code for FAB with Bottom Navigation View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabCradleMargin="5dp"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp">
<!--        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp"-->

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:itemIconSize="15dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
            app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:menu="@menu/scan_app_menu" />

<!--android:background="@null"-->

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tint="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/scanqr"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_color_for_scanning_btn"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Drawable xml resource Code called: gradient_color_for_scanning_btn**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="50dp"
            android:shape="oval">

            <corners android:radius="10dp" />

            <gradient
                android:startColor="#1fb8fc"
                android:angle="18"
                android:endColor="#0A5F8A" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/scanqr" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**My dependencies**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kamranullah.bottomnavscanapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

**Logcat Result:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kamranullah.bottomnavscanapp/com.kamranullah.bottomnavscanapp.MainActivity}: **android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton**
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3320)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7410)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 **Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton**
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
    at com.kamranullah.bottomnavscanapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7410) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
 **Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton**
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
    at com.kamranullah.bottomnavscanapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7410) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
 **Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)**
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
    at com.kamranullah.bottomnavscanapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7410) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
 **Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/gradient_color_for_scanning_btn.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070072**
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4287)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4156)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4006)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4249)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:150)
    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:85)
    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:81)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.VisibilityAwareImageButton.<init>(VisibilityAwareImageButton.java:47)
    at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:207)
    at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:201)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
    at com.kamranullah.bottomnavscanapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3267) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7410) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
 **Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #10<gradient> tag requires 'angle' attribute to be a multiple of 45**
```

**What I want to achieve:**
[Needed is encircled with red line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bflK0.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the root issue is identified by the following line in the logcat trace:

```
**Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #10<gradient> tag requires 'angle' attribute to be a multiple of 45**
```

The angle that you have in the drawable is `18`. From the documenation for [ShapeDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape):

> <gradient>
> Specifies a gradient color for the shape.
>
> attributes:
>
> android:angle
> Integer. The angle for the gradient, in degrees. 0 is left to right, 90 is bottom to top. It must be a multiple of 45. Default is 0.

Try changing the angle to a multiple of 45 to see if that eliminates the crash. If so, you can then address how to otherwise go about getting the drawable you need.

---

Update:

I assume that the crash problem is resolved, but you don't see the FAB you want. It doesn't seem that the background attribute of the FAB is supported. Try the following:

**gradient_color_for_scanning_btn.xml**
This will get the rotated background without the crash. From the image you posted, it looks like a -90 degree rotation on the shape will get you what you want. If you find you need a rotation other than the -90 degree rotation, uncomment the `rotate` tag and specify the rotation you want.

I also added a ripple since the ripple will be lost on the true FAB background since it is covered up.

```
<layer-list>
    <item>
        <ripple android:color="@color/black">
            <item>
<!--                <rotate-->
<!--                    android:fromDegrees="90"-->
<!--                    android:pivotX="50%"-->
<!--                    android:pivotY="50%"-->
<!--                    android:toDegrees="90">-->
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <gradient
                                android:angle="-90"
                                android:endColor="#0A5F8A"
                                android:startColor="#1fb8fc" />
                        </shape>
<!--                </rotate>-->
            </item>
        </ripple>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/scanqr" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Finally, define the FAB in the layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/gradient_color_for_scanning_btn"
    app:maxImageSize="56dp"/>
```

You should now see something like this:

[image]

Comment: I tried your code, but nothing happened sir. The drawable does not affect the FAB button in any way. It is like the drawable resource is not used on the FAB view. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The whole button is shown as a black circle with the icon corner outside of the background and that corner is also black. means icon and FAB both are black anyway, thank you for your effort sir.

Comment: @KamranKhan Sorry it's not working for you. I've posted my [demo project](https://github.com/Cheticamp/FabImage) on GitHub if you want to try it out.

Comment: Ok sir, I'll check it. Thank you.